# MediaBrowser not connecting to MediaBrowserService

Tags: android, android-activity, foreground-service, mediabrowserservice, mediabrowser

I'm trying to connect to a MediaBrowserService from an activity using a MediaBrowser. However, my `onConnected` callback never seems to be called to allow me to set up the `MediaController` and start manipulating playback.

In my player/browser activity:

```
private final MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback mConnectionCallback =
            new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected() {
                    try {
                        mMediaController =
                                new MediaControllerCompat(
                                        PlayActivity.this,
                                        mMediaBrowser.getSessionToken()
                                );

                        mMediaController.registerCallback(mControllerCallback);

                        mControllerCallback
                                .onMetadataChanged(mMediaController.getMetadata());
                        mControllerCallback
                                .onPlaybackStateChanged(mMediaController.getPlaybackState());
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                    mMediaController
                            .getTransportControls()
                            .prepareFromUri(
                                    Uri.parse(
                                            getIntent()
                                                    .getStringExtra(StreamingService.STREAM_URI)),
                                    getIntent().getExtras());

                    mMediaController
                            .getTransportControls().play();

                    buildTransportControls();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended() { }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed() { }
            };

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mMediaBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(this,
                new ComponentName(this, StreamingService.class),
                mConnectionCallback,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMediaBrowser.connect();
    }
```

I've added breakpoints with the debugger and it seems that execution does reach the service, to the end of its `onCreate` method, but execution never seems to reach either the `onConnected` or `onConnectionFailed` methods of my connection callback. After `connect` is called, checked `isConnected` returns false.

I'm not sure how to debug further as the problem is happening somewhere during the connection process, and as far as I can tell my code conforms to Android example guides. And yes I am calling `setSessionToken` in `onCreate` of the browser service.

If I try to set up the MediaController in `onStart` of my activity, after I call `connect`, I get an exception stating that the browser is not connected and so the session token cannot be set. So although execution goes into `onCreate` of my service, the connection is not completing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the bug. I was overriding the following method in my `StreamingService` (`MediaBrowserServiceCompat`) class:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Removing the method completely allows the connection to take place.

Comment: Do you have an explanation why this is the case? What if you have another fragment bounded to the service and still want control from another place?

Comment: It does not work when you bound your service to an activity!